# DSpace: images appears just at initial page

Tags: html, image, dspace

My code is as follows:

```
<h3 class="ds-option-set-head">Compartilhar</h3>
            <div class="ds-option-set" id="sharebar">
                    <ul>
                            <li onclick="shareFunction('fb')"><img src="themes/UFSC_producao/images/facebook.svg"></img></li>
                            <li onclick="shareFunction('tw')"><img src="themes/UFSC_producao/images/twitter.svg"></img></li>
                            <li onclick="shareFunction('lk')"><img src="themes/UFSC_producao/images/linkedin.svg"></img></li>
                            <li onclick="shareFunction('gp')"><img src="themes/UFSC_producao/images/google-plus.svg"></img></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
```

These images just appears at the initial page *mysite/xmlui* and I don't know why. Any suggestions?

Comment: You probably need absolute paths.

Comment: I already tried it. In this case, it doesn't work even on the initial page.

Comment: You probably have the wrong path.  Look at the network tab.

Comment: Error 404. However, the "Transferred" column is showing 65kb...

Comment: Look at the URL and figure out why it's wrong.

Comment: It's working just on the initial page because on this case it's trying to find on: _myurl/xmlui/themes/UFSC..../_. Any other pages it try to find on _myurl/xmlui/blabla.../.../themes/UFSC.../_ which doesn't exist. Any suggestions of how can I fix it?

Comment: You need to use an absolute path that actually exists.

Comment: If I use the absolute path it will try to find _mysite/xmlui/absolutepath_ and will not work. I think that I should change something else, on another config file I guess.

Comment: your absolute path has to start with `http://` or `https://` (or `//` for both)

Comment: I just fixed it. I had to use _<xsl:value-of select="$context-path" />_ and it's now working.